# exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x65b3dc4e]], closing connection. java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, logstash

My es was working fine with logstash with this config:

es config file:

```
cluster.name: rb_dev
node.data: true
node.name: test_01_dev
path.data: /data/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: 255.255.255.255
http.port: 9200
```

Then I needed to run some groovy scripts so I first stopped logstash and then I stopped elasticsearch and then added these lines to config file:

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
```

Then I started the elastic search and check the log file and this error started coming...

The log file shows this error:

```
[2016-04-15 12:11:06,800][INFO ][node                     ] [test_01_dev] version[2.2.0], pid[6383], build[8ff36d1/2016-01-27T13:32:39Z]
[2016-04-15 12:11:06,801][INFO ][node                     ] [test_01_dev] initializing ...
[2016-04-15 12:11:07,325][INFO ][plugins                  ] [test_01_dev] modules [lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-04-15 12:11:07,343][INFO ][env                      ] [test_01_dev] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/data (/dev/xvdf)]], net usable_space [65.2gb], net total_space [98.3gb], spins? [no], types [ext4]
[2016-04-15 12:11:07,343][INFO ][env                      ] [test_01_dev] heap size [1007.3mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-04-15 12:11:09,366][INFO ][node                     ] [test_01_dev] initialized
[2016-04-15 12:11:09,366][INFO ][node                     ] [test_01_dev] starting ...
[2016-04-15 12:11:09,499][INFO ][transport                ] [test_01_dev] publish_address {255.255.255.255:9301}, bound_addresses {[::]:9301}
[2016-04-15 12:11:09,510][INFO ][discovery                ] [test_01_dev] rb_dev/Rz88xk-BS5uItGujo68ihw
[2016-04-15 12:11:12,579][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [test_01_dev] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x65b3dc4e]], closing connection
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:70)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:634)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:216)
        at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:229)
        at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:182)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:951)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:903)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:876)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:243)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.joinElectedMaster(ZenDiscovery.java:419)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innerJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:371)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$5000(ZenDiscovery.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$JoinThreadControl$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:1260)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-04-15 12:11:12,586][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [test_01_dev] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x9685c7ee]], closing connection
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:70)
```

Now, even when I commented the change I am still getting the error.
I tried adding:

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

...but the error persists.